# Where is the cassandra.yaml location on the MAC?

Tags: database, cassandra, insert

I am working on the docker environment, and executed `docker exec -it mycassandra cqlsh`. Then, I am inserting the data, and it is occurring the following error:

[WriteTimeout - Error from server: code=1100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BvJg.jpg)

By [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819035/write-timeout-thrown-by-cassandra-datastax-driver), it tells me that I need to find out the `cassandra.yaml` document and amend the write-time, but I can not find that on my MAC.

Could you tell me how can I find it and how to amend the document?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

for those who have installed it as `brew install cassandra`, yaml file will located in `usr/local/etc/cassandra`

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the official cassandra image then `cassandra.yaml` may be found at `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` in the container. If you want to create a custom `cassandra.yaml` file then you may try to overwrite it in your `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` file. For example, in my `docker-compose.yml` file I have something like:

```
services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.11.4
    volumes:
    - ./cassandra.yaml:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

which causes the `cassandra.yaml` file in the container to be overwritten by my local `cassandra.yaml`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS :

It will be found in either of the below locations:

1. Cassandra package installations: `/etc/cassandra`
2. Cassandra tarball installations: `install_location/conf`
3. DataStax Enterprise package installations: `/etc/dse/cassandra`
4. DataStax Enterprise tarball installations: `install_location/resources/cassandra/conf`

Comment: do we have packages for Mac? ;-) Also the question is about location of file in the Docker image...

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed Cassandra from the home-brew then you can find the cassandra.yaml file in the below path.

**/opt/homebrew/etc/cassandra**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From the provided example, it seems that the database is executed from inside a container. So the cassandra.yaml that you're looking for will be created on the fly when the container is started up, based on the configuration that you provided.

We have set Cassandra Containers with Kubernetes, and execute them in docker, based on the instructions found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/), and been able to modify the settings of the cassandra.yaml file in the configuration of the statefulset, updating the variables in `env` for the spec of the container.

For example, to modify the seeds list, the cluster name, and the rack of the C* cluster named `c-test-qa`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
...
spec:
  serviceName: c-test-qa
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: c-test-qa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: c-test-qa
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: c-test-qa
          image: cassandra:3.11
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
...
          env:
            - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
              value: c-test-qa-0.c-test-qa.qa.svc.cluster.local
            - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
              value: "testqa"
            - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
              value: "DC1"
            - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
              value: "CustomRack1"
...
```